# Applying for a Student visa in Hungary?

Tags: visa, resident-permit, student-visa, schengen, hungarian-citizens

I have found my self in a very confusing situation and I really need to plan quickly.
I'm an Iranian citizen and I've been admitted in CEU in Budapest for a one year course starting from September. However, I'm planning to take part in two summer schools in Germany in August. The problem is that both cases there is a long procedure awaiting and also the time of each visa might overlap the other for a few days. furthermore, I'm waiting for another university to answer me and I might even change my mind.
Do you think that could justify my intention to apply for a 90 day stay and then apply for my Student permit inside Budapest? my courses in Germany finish on 28th of August and my classes in Budapest starts on 4th of September.So I don't really have time to go back to my country in between.

Comment: Another possibility: you may be able to apply for your Hungarian student visa at a Hungarian consulate in Germany.  See https://berlin.mfa.gov.hu/deu/page/magyar-konzulatusok-nemetorszagban to find out which one is responsible for the places where you'll be.